# How to list recent files added to a GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket with a large number of files in it. I want to list the most recent files added to the bucket. I know I could (in theory) list all the files using

```
gsutil ls gs://my_bucket/**
```

and then pipe the output through a filter using sed/awk. However the number of files is so large that the gsutil query will need ages to run. Is there a built in query that will list only the most recently created files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GCS doesn't support a way to query by date. If you need an efficient way to do that (e.g., if you do this regularly over a bucket with millions or more objects) you could configure object change notifications and have an app that subscribes to the notifications and tracks the N most recently added ones.